# How to get some info from text to combobox in vb

Tags: vb.net

This is my first question here and I  don't know what to say but I will try to explain.

Now I have a text file that contains:

```
[2000] name : any thing job : doctor age : 50
[2002] name : anything else job : anything age : 60
[2003] name : anything else job : anything else age : 55
```

How can I get every thing inside this [ ] in a combobox so the combobox items should be 2000, 2002, 2003? Btw, my text file have a **lot of** lines so i can't do it with lines.

My second question if I have numbers in combobox for example

```
64080 
65090 
62055
```

What code can remove the last number from every item in the combobox to be:

```
6408
6509
6205
```

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't do it with lines"?  I don't understand what you meant by that and it seems important.  Can you elaborate on that point?

Comment: Do you not know how to (1) provide values for a ComboBox, or (2) manipulate the input to the form you want. For (2), try taking a look at the [methods on the String class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) like `IndexOf` and `Substring`. Think about how you could use those. Try to break your question into smaller pieces and look for answers to those smaller pieces. If you have more information to add, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28236264/edit/) rather than responding in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this module gives a good starting point:

```
Imports System.IO.File
Module NumModule

    Function GetNumbers(ByVal PathString As String) As Integer()

        Dim Line As String
        Dim IntTable() As Integer
        'Determines line count
        Dim LineCount = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(PathString).Length - 1
        ReDim IntTable(LineCount)
        'Initiating counter 
        Dim Counter As Integer = 0
        'Copying numbers into Intable
        Dim stream As New IO.StreamReader(PathString)
        For Counter = 0 To LineCount
            Line = stream.ReadLine
            Dim PosS As Integer
            Dim PosE As Integer
            PosE = Line.IndexOf("]") - 1
            PosS = Line.IndexOf("[") + 1
            Dim Number As Integer
            Number = CInt(Line.Substring(PosS, PosE))
            IntTable(Counter) = Number
        Next Counter
        stream.Close()
        GetNumbers = IntTable
    End Function
End Module
```

Later, add a combobox to your form (We'll call it `Form1`) and double click on it to get to `Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`.

From there, you can now add your numbers to your combobox using a `For` loop that starts from 0 and ends with the `Ubound(NumModule.GetNumbers(StringPath:="YourStringPathHere",1)`. like follow:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim counter As Integer = UBound(NumModule.GetNumbers(PathString:="D:\Test.txt"), 1)
        For i As Integer = 0 To counter

            ComboBox1.Items.Add(NumModule.GetNumbers(PathString:="D:\Test.txt")(i).ToString)

        Next
    End Sub
```

To answer your second question, replace `Form1_load`'s content with the following:

```
 Dim counter As Integer = UBound(NumModule.GetNumbers(PathString:="D:\Test.txt"), 1)
    For i As Integer = 0 To counter
        Dim TrimmedString As String = NumModule.GetNumbers(PathString:="D:\Test.txt")(i).ToString
        If Len(TrimmedString) = 5 Then
            TrimmedString = TrimmedString.Remove(TrimmedString.Length - 1)
        End If
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(TrimmedString)

    Next
```

My end-result:

[image]

Comment: About your second question? Do you want trim the four digit number to three digit number?

Comment: yea about the second one i wanna to remove the last number ( its four digit number to 4 digit number)
64080 to 6408

Comment: http://i.epvpimg.com/DqJIc.jpg
check that pic it has my comment LOL i dunno how to do a comment here XD

Comment: You need to have your text formatted like it is in the question.

Comment: I could've used a `regex` to find the matches if I had known your text was like that of your the image. Couldn't be bothered now.

Comment: i wasnt able to write the question like the image always got error
but your answer helped me a lot 
I will remove all lines from the text so it be formatted like it is in the question and work ;)
thanks!